Recreate classic table of contents with KOMA class
I want to recreate the table of contents of a classic book by means provided with KOMA document classes. Here is a sample page of said table of contents, taken from "Linear Algebra, 2nd Edition" by Serge Lang:

Due to layout rules for the remainder of the book, "Contents" is already centred as a chapter heading. I have found the package "fmtcount" to print counters as words; for the respective part pages this works as intended.
Using \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[breakafternumber=true]{tocline}{part, chapter} it is possible to get the line break after the chapter counter, but it doesn't seem to work with the option entryformat=\centering.
My question is: How do I define the respective rules for chapter and part headings to recreate what is shown in the picture? I realise I could probably find out the answer with enough trial and error and skimming the documentation, but maybe someone already knows how to do this?
Here is an MWE demonstration of how far I have gotten on my own:
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, twoside=true, twocolumn=false, headings=standardclasses, DIV=calc, open=right, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
% Definitions for chapter and section headings
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}.}
% Headings font
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}
% Part headings for part pages
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\NUMBERstring{part}}
\addtokomafont{partprefix}{\MakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{part}{\MakeUppercase}
%Chapter prefix in uppercase
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalfont\MakeUppercase} 
%Section headings centred
\let\raggedsection\centering 
%Section headings in bold italics
\addtokomafont{section}{\itshape}
%Subsections to be exlusively used for "Exercises"
\let\raggedsubsection\centering 
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}% Figure numbering
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}%Figure lables

\newcommand{\ignoreonearg}[1]{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberbox=\ignoreonearg]{part} % No page number for part in ToC
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberbox=\ignoreonearg]{chapter} % No page number for chapter in ToC
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[breakafternumber=true]{tocline}{part, chapter}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Basic Theory}
\blinddocument
\chapter{Vectors}
\end{document}


On this site,
a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I
get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application
(e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this
complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too
localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a
minimal working example (MWE):
you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Sorry for not providing an MWE, I added one to the question. Thanks for your answer already, I will try to modify it accordingly.

Unfortunately originally you've not shown a minimal working example of what you've tried so far, so following is only a sketch of what can be done.
KOMA-Script package tocbasic, which is used by scrbook, provides command \DeclareTOCEntryStyle to define new entry styles. For a not configurable style it is quite easy to use, e.g.:
\DeclareTOCEntryStyle{centernopage}{%
  \begingroup
    \par
    \centering
    \renewcommand*\numberline[1]{\csname #1name\endcsname\ ####1\par\nobreak}%
    ##1\par
    \bigskip
  \endgroup
}

would define a new style, that centers the number, followed by the text. Note: #1 is the name of the level, in your case, e.g., part or chapter. So \csname #1name\endcsname in your case would be, e.g., \partname or \chaptername. ##1 is the second argument of the \contentsline command and ##2 is the third argument of the \contentsline command. The ####1 in the example is the argument of \numberline.
Now, you can use \DeclareTOCStyleEntries to uses this style, e.g., for chapter and part entries:
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}
\let\raggedchapter\centering% from the ToC heading it seems, you want this

\DeclareTOCEntryStyle{centernopage}{%
  \begingroup
    \par
    \centering
    \renewcommand*\numberline[1]{\csname #1name\endcsname\ ####1\par\nobreak}%
    ##1\par
    \bigskip
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{centernopage}{part,chapter}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Basic Theory}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


If you need a more configurable style, see the predefined styles in tocbasic.sty and for a start also see my answer to Alignt ToC around space between chapter titles and page numbers. A more detailed example can be found in the KOMA-Script Wiki in English: How to display the table of contents entries with the page number first followed by the heading, and also in German: Wie die Inhaltsverzeichniseinträge zuerst die Seitenzahl gefolgt von der Überschrift anzeigen.
